# Update multiple rows using select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have these tables and values:

```
Table1
------------------------
ID | Value
------------------------
 2 | asdf
 4 | fdsa
 5 | aaaa

Table2
------------------------
ID | Value
------------------------
 2 | bbbb
 4 | bbbb
 5 | bbbb
```

I want to update all the values in `Table2` using the values in `Table1` with their respective ID's.

I know I can run this:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET Value = t1.Value
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

But what can I do if `Table1` and `Table2` are actually select statements with criteria? How can I modify the SQL statement to take that into consideration?

Comment: Correlate both your Select Statements with `Table2` using joins and then fire the update on `Table2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how such update queries are generally done in Oracle. Oracle doesn't have an `UPDATE FROM` option:

```
UPDATE table2 t2
   SET t2.value = ( SELECT t1.value FROM table1 t1
                     WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID )
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
                 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID );
```

The `WHERE EXISTS` clause will make sure that only the rows with a corresponding row in `table1` are updated (otherwise *every row* in `table2` will be updated; those without corresponding rows in `table1` will be updated to `NULL`).